# The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing a project using asp.net mvc3.
I know this is a duplicate question however I tried some way like this one

```
Right click on solution --> Properties    
Look under Common Properties --> Startup Project    
Select multiple startup projects    
select Start action on the projects you need to debug.
```

`Goto Project Properties -> Build -> Advanced...
 In the "Output" section select "full" in Debug Info dropdown`

but nothing happen. But for my controllers and repositories are workings but for my Javascript not working. Can't trace well :(

Comment: Are you trying to add a breakpoint to Javascript code in designer ?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in JS

Comment: I assume you're trying to debug javascript code in IDE (As I am still not clear on what your requirement is). If so try to debug Javascript code through your browser's Developer tools.

Comment: I am currently debugging in my browser(chrome) because in my JS it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 reasons I know why this is happening:

- First you might have enabled the JS Bundling and
- Second you are not running your web application in IE.

You may check if JS bundling is enabled in BundleConfig.cs

Comment: Even I run it in IE still not working I don't why. And about Bundling I don't have like that. Newbie here.

Comment: Sorry I don't have like that. All I see is Web.config and package.config

Comment: its not .config file, it is a .cs file BundleConfig.cs is normally located in AppStart folder..  but if you don't see any in the solution explorer then this will not help you ..

Comment: sorry I don't have that kind of folder :( but thanks for the time. I will wait for others to comment.